# Counting sign definiteness in BRST cohomology of string

Tags: operators, string-theory, brst

In Polchinksi ch-$4$ following manipulation is done:
$$|\psi_1\rangle=(e\cdot\alpha_{-1}+\beta b_{-1}+\gamma c_{-1})|0,\textbf{k}\rangle .\tag{4.3.25}$$
$$\langle\psi_1|\psi_1\rangle=\Big(e^*\cdot e+(\beta^*\cdot\gamma+\gamma^*\cdot\beta)\Big)\langle0,\textbf k|0,\textbf k' \rangle.\tag{4.3.26}$$
The first line is a definition of state $\psi_1$ while in the second line we use hermitian conjugate and reduced inner product (ignoring $0$th component of $\textbf k$ and zero mode of ghost). My doubt lies in following line:

> Going to the orthogonal basis there are 26 positive-norm states and 2 negative-norm states.

I am unable to deduce the signs from $(4.3.26)$ I have reasoned  things like following:
the $||$ inner product is there for probabilistic interpretation so it has to be positive only hence can be neglected. Now the $e^{\mu}$ is a polarisation vector so it will have D components but what sign will it contribute and same goes for the $\beta, \gamma$ terms. Are these sign deduced from behavior of $\alpha, b, c$ operator?

Answer (score 1):

Take an orthogonal basis for the $e_\mu$ where the $\nu$'th element of $e_\mu$ is given by $\delta_\mu^\nu$. You then have $e_0 = (1, 0, \cdots, 0)$ and thus $(e_0)^2 =-1$. All the $e_i$ have   $(e_i)^2= +1$. That is one negative norm state and 25 positive norm states. For the ghost excitations,  take a basis for which the corresponding state has $\beta^* \gamma$ real. Then $\beta^* \gamma = (\beta^* \gamma)^** = -\gamma^* \beta$,  the extra sign because of the Grassmann character. Thus $\beta^* \gamma$ and $\gamma^* \beta$ have opposite signs; one of them is necessarily positive norm,  and the other one negative norm. You thus have indeed 26 positive norm states and two negative norm states.

Comment: I understood the logic but I can't understand why $\beta,\gamma$ have to be Grassmann numbers? $\beta ^* \gamma$ has to be real since it's an S matrix element but product of two Grassmannian number is not real number.